# How do I fix empty property values in an array of objects with different value type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects returned from database. Goal is to calculate the percentage of marks for each id. For some objects marks are stored in array whereas for some it is just a normal variable.

```
const data=[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "marks": [40.25],   
  },
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "marks": [70,80],
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "marks": 60,
  },
  {
    "Id":5,
    "marks": [],
  }
]
let res=[]
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    let rbp=[]
    dbp=data[i].marks
    for(var j=0;j<dbp.length;j++)
    {
        const tmp=(parseFloat(dbp[j])/80)*(90/100)
        rbp.push(tmp)
    }
    console.log(rbp)
    res.push({
        iD:data[i].Id,
        PERCENTAGE:rbp
    })
}
console.log(res)
```

the above code generates the following output

```
[ { iD: 1, PERCENTAGE: [ 0.45281250000000006 ] },
  { iD: 7, PERCENTAGE: [ 0.7875, 0.9 ] },
  { iD: 2, PERCENTAGE: [] },
  { iD: 5, PERCENTAGE: [] } ]
```

Percentage of marks for the penultimate object just returns an empty array. I tried getting the typeof marks but it returns object for both array and non array. How do I fix this?

Comment: `Array.isArray()` will tell you if a value is an array or not.  And, `typeof` will tell you if the value is a Number or not.

Comment: Could you not just standardise the data from the database? Why would you have an empty array but _also_ a value that's a single integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can standardised the `marks` to array by checking if `marks` is array using `Array.isArray()` and convert number to array. Then you can use your existing logic.

```js
const data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "marks": [40.25],
  },
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "marks": [70, 80],
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "marks": 60,
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "marks": [],
  }
]
let res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let rbp = [];
  const dbp = Array.isArray(data[i].marks) ? data[i].marks: [data[i].marks];
  for (var j = 0; j < dbp.length; j++) {
    const tmp = (dbp[j] / 80) * (90 / 100);
    rbp.push(tmp);
  }
  res.push({
    ID: data[i].Id,
    PERCENTAGE: rbp
  })
}
console.log(res)
```

You can also use functional style to accomplish it.

```js
const data=[ { "Id": 1, "marks": [40.25], }, { "Id": 7, "marks": [70,80], }, { "Id": 2, "marks": 60, }, { "Id":5, "marks": [], } ],
      result = data.map(o => {
        const marks = Array.isArray(o.marks) ? o.marks: [o.marks];
        const percentage = marks.map((mark) => (mark/80) * (90/100));
        return { ID: o.id, PERCENTAGE: percentage };
      });
console.log(result);
```